# How can i add a text to a mesh so it doesn't destroy my mesh?

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, texture-baking, baking

[image]
I am trying to finish high poly mesh of the wrench so i can later bake it to the lower poly model of it, but i have no idea how can i add the text without  destroying my mesh. I want it to stand out a little bit to achieve effect such us one in  the picture below.

[image]

I have tried using boolean modifier, difference and then extruding engraved text but it didn't end up very well( using shade smooth resulted in awful shading).I also thought about baking the text separately but i don't know if that is possible. Here is the link to the blend file.

http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=52362

Comment: You can keep the text as separate object. Just select the wrench and text when baking to the low poly object.

Comment: it depends if you're looking for a smooth welding or not between the text and the surface, if not, as Rjg says, it can simply be another mesh

Comment: What would be the solution if i wanted smooth welding as a result ?